# Uploadify broken in Wicket 1.5.8 (with JQWicket)

Tags: wicket, uploadify, wicket-1.5

This might help someone else...

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WICKET-4715

Results in the following errors on uploading of any files:

```
ERROR - MultipartFormInputStream   - Error while reading servlet request multi-part data:    
Stream ended unexpectedly. boundary='------------Ij5KM7Ij5Ij5KM7cH2gL6Ef1GI3GI3I3';    
bufSize=4096
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: upgrade to Wicket 1.5.9!